# How to make EndInvoke generic?

Tags: c#, events, generics, asynchronous, event-handling

In my code I raise events using `BeginInvoke`, but because each event has different `EventArgs`, my code is full of duplicate functions, like:

```
private void EndAsyncConnect(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    var ar = (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)iar;
    var invokedMethod = (EventHandler<InfoArgs>)ar.AsyncDelegate;

    invokedMethod.EndInvoke(iar);
}

private void EndAsyncReceived(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    var ar = (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)iar;
    var invokedMethod = (EventHandler<ReceivedArgs>)ar.AsyncDelegate;

    invokedMethod.EndInvoke(iar);
}
```

Is there a way to make the EndAsync function generic for all events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your event delegate types are `EventHandler<T>`, this should work:

```
void CompletionCallback<T>(IAsyncResult iar)
    where T : EventArgs
{
    var ar = (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)iar;
    var invokedMethod = (EventHandler<T>)ar.AsyncDelegate;
    invokedMethod.EndInvoke(iar);
}
```